# Kendo ui jsonp data binding

Tags: kendo-ui, jsonp

I'm struggling with the kendo ui `transport` property for schedules. The following snippet worked as expected:

```js
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://myurl',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: "myCallback",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: "GET"
    });
    
    function myCallback(result){
        
     $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
            date: new Date("2022/03/01"),
            startTime: new Date("2022/03/01 07:00 AM"),
            height: 600,
            views: [
                "day",
                { type: "workWeek", selected: true },
                "week",
                "month",
                "agenda",
                { type: "timeline", eventHeight: 50}
            ],
            timezone: "Etc/UTC",
            dataSource: result      
        });
    }
```

As the [kendo ui tutorials](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/scheduling/scheduler/binding) mentioned there should be a shortcut for definition above; but the result of the following code snippet is a calendar with no events.

```js
     $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
            date: new Date("2022/03/01"),
            startTime: new Date("2022/03/01 07:00 AM"),
            height: 600,
            views: [
                "day",
                { type: "workWeek", selected: true },
                "week",
                "month",
                "agenda",
                { type: "timeline", eventHeight: 50}
            ],
            timezone: "Etc/UTC",
            dataSource:         {
                batch: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "https://myurl",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    }
                    
                }
        
            }       
        });
```

Comment: What is `jsonpCallbackString`?

Comment: @ShawnOrr You are right, the `jsonpCallbackString` is not in the documentation I linked above. Pls see my edits.

Comment: I would look into setting the [schema](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/schema) as well. Maybe that is needed in this situation.